# Assertion error: involving the fscanf function

Tags: c, runtime-error, scanf

This error occurred in my program:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program:C:\JM\.\bin\ldecod.exe
File: f:\ff\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\fscanf.c
Line:52

Expression: (stream!=NULL)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application.)
```

What seems to be the problem here?

### CODE

This is the portion of my code where I used fscanf. When mi=297 it worked perfectly fine.

```
int myframe[29699];
........

if (CONCEAL==1)
{
  FILE*concealfile;
  concealfile=fopen("myerrsim%15carphone.txt","r");
  for(mi=0; mi<14850; mi++)
  {
      fscanf(concealfile,"%d\n", &myframe[mi]);
  }
  if (myctr==currMB->mbAddrX+(((currMB)->p_Slice)->p_Img)->number*99 && currMB->mbAddrX+(((currMB)->p_Slice)->p_Img)->number>0)
  {
      if (myframe[myctr]==1)
      {
          mbmode=0;
      }
      myctr++;
  }
}
```

> Additional questions! I am encountering several similar errors. The
>   programs breaks at different portions of  source codes and some of
>   which are built in functions like "fscanf". I do not know the reason.
>   And sometimes a program on my computer, like "Flash Player" notifies
>   me of some sort of error. Is this because the pointers used in my
>   program are trying to access "Flash Player"? Why is this happening and
>   what is the possible fix?

**What are assertion errors simply put?**

**For @Jonathan Leffler**

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
        /*
         * Report error.
         *
         * If _CRT_ERROR has _CRTDBG_REPORT_WNDW on, and user chooses
         * "Retry", call the debugger.
         *
         * Otherwise, continue execution.
         *
         */

        if (rterrnum != _RT_CRNL && rterrnum != _RT_BANNER && rterrnum != _RT_CRT_NOTINIT)
        {
            switch (_CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ERROR, NULL, 0, NULL, L"%s", error_text))
            {
  ->        case 1: _CrtDbgBreak(); msgshown = 1; break;
            case 0: msgshown = 1; break;
            }
        }
```

where -> is the unexpected breakpoint.
located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\crt0msg.c

Comment: wait its not showing up i'll try again.

Comment: Please copy/paste the comment..

Comment: The image is difficult to read and there's very little information about your program surrounding the `fscanf` call.

Comment: Apparently I have not enough reputation that's why the image is not showing up. I have inserted the error in text. Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't get what is unclear about my question. I did not know that I am not allowed to post pictures earlier. I have already edited my question. I have even put the code. I'm putting all my effort to make this question as clear as possible. What is not so clear about my question?

Comment: @ManojPandey the image cannot be posted.

Comment: I really thought this is a common error in C that any experienced programmer would know. And yet nobody can answer my question. I don't think I have to put my code. It's about using fscanf. Hasn't anybody encounter this?

Comment: how can my question be possibly put on hold? i think it's my revisions made it so clear already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you did something like:

```
char name[64];
FILE *fp = fopen("c:/non-existent/file", "r");
fscanf(fp, "%s", name);
```

without checking that `fopen()` was successful, and `fprintf()` triggered an assertion failure.  When `fopen()` fails, it returns a NULL pointer, and the assertion says `stream != NULL` (where 'stream' is a file stream, the first argument to `fscanf(), and means a`FILE *`such as`fp`).

There's an outside chance that you use `fscanf_s()` because you're on Windows — it's the same basic story, but `fscanf_s()` checks for such problems where `fscanf()` does not.

Possible fix:

```
char name[64];
FILE *fp = fopen("c:/non-existent/file", "r");
if (fp == 0)
    ...report failure to open file (and exit or return)...
if (fscanf(fp, "%s", name) != 1)
    ...report read failure...
```

Comment: It worked earlier. But as I add more text to be read from the textfile I was reading from, this error appeared.

Comment: Then go back to the working version, or the reduced size text file.  Or show the code so we can see what you're doing wrong.  Working blind (whether because we're trying to read the image — now gone — or because we don't have your code) makes life hard.  It is best if you create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Okay i'll post it shortly. What I was reading from the textfile is a random error. i can't reduce the size since the number of errors required is 14850. The 297 errors I used is just for testing whether my program is working or not.

Comment: I have opened the .exe file of my program in cmd. is this the possible cause of the problem?

Comment: You don't check that the file was opened, exactly as I postulated.  Do you really have a file with a `%` in its name?  You also don't check the result of `fscanf()`.  You don't show the declaration of `myframe` — in fact, you didn't read up on how to create an SSCCE at all.  It is conceivable that you're running into trouble because you're indexing out of bounds in the `myframe` array, especially if it seems to work for smaller numbers and not for larger numbers.

Comment: "It is conceivable that you're running into trouble because you're indexing out of bounds in the myframe array, especially if it seems to work for smaller numbers and not for larger numbers." what does this mean? I declared myframe as int myframe[29699] somewhere in the program. and what is sscce?

Comment: I explained SSCCE in my first comment — please read it.  "It is conceivable..." means that because you didn't show your you declaration of `int myframe[29699];` in the code, people trying to answer your question have no idea what you've declared `myframe` as and if you access arrays out of bounds, funny things can happen.  If you declared `int myframe[29699];`, then it is less likely to be the trouble — but we can't read your source code if you don't show it to us! As stated before: you need to create a minimal program that reproduces your problem and include the complete code in the question.

Comment: so there should be no problem since i declared the size of myframe? should i declare myframe as a global variable to the c file or declare it inside the function where the above code is located? The said function is traversed for 14850 times and at some point a notification from my flashplayer pops out. i think it is being accessed maybe because of "bad pointers?". and is the for loop legal there? i mean everytime the function is traversed it reads the textfile. so my main dilemma i think is where to declare myframe to not cause a memory error. btw you really helped me a lot already.

Comment: is this an assertion? "
if (fp == 0)
    ...report failure to open file (and exit or return)...". I'm not sure if i undertood correctly. so the conditional statement here needs a return value to determine if the process is successful?

Comment: See `#include <assert.h>` and `assert(fp != 0);`.  The header defines a macro (subject to `#if !defined(NDEBUG)`) called `assert()`.  The macro evaluates the expression (`fp != 0` in my example) and does nothing if it is true.  If the expression is false, though, it prints an error message and aborts the program.  The expression identifies the source file, line number, sometimes the function name (C99 and later), and usually the expression text.  That is different from an error test such as `if (fp == 0)`.  An assertion should never fire; it is a catastrophe if it does.  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ An error test is half-expected to fire. For example, people will mistype file names, or files or directories will be removed, or disks will be full, or any of a myriad other things may happen to prevent a file being opened successfully. So, testing for an error on `fopen()` is necessary common sense. By contrast, an assertion might be used when it is a programming error for the condition to be violated. If a function requires a non-null pointer, then you might have `void *some_func(void *ptr) { assert(ptr != 0); ...use pointer... }`. It's a bug if the assertion fails.

Comment: Regarding your earlier question ('so there should be no problem if...'): Avoid global variables.  If the array is big enough, you shouldn't be having overflow problems.  However, Flashplayer popping up is pretty weird behaviour.  It suggests that there is a problem somewhere in your code — not necessarily in the bit we're looking at so far.

Comment: But why does it break on built in functions and on some of my source codes. i cannot find the assertion statement where the program encountered an unexpected breakpoint. so what do you think the problem really is? the textfile is existing btw.

Comment: The assertion that was/is firing is in the Microsoft C run-time library — but as a result of your code miscalling the function.  The trouble is probably not directly in the code where it is spotted; it is probably somewhere else.  This is common with errant memory issues — you spot them far distant from where the trouble is caused.  If you were on Linux, I'd tell you to get `valgrind` busy.  You aren't, and I'm not sure what the equivalent is.

Comment: found the assert! it was on my code! how can i solve this????????

Comment: if i make myframe sa local variable will it consume a lot of memory everytime i initialize it? because it will be initialized every function call.

Comment: I can't answer 'how to solve the assert' because I don't have your code or a Windows machine to run it on.  If your `myframe` is a local variable, it will be created each time the function is called; if it has initialization, it will be initialized each time the function is called.  (I'd invite you to chat but you don't have enough reputation yet to do that.)

Comment: i can actually send you the file. it has four projects. i really don't understand why there is an error. i will also post some codes where the program encounters an unexpected breakpoint. but you said the trouble may probably be somewhere else. Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: See my profile for my email address.

Comment: Also what can I put in "
    ...report failure to open file (and exit or return)..."? do i have to include the two conditions above?

Comment: " check your file pointer. It is possible that your file failed to open with your fopen call or something else caused it to put the value of the pointer to NULL." which i read across the internet. if this happens what will i do to have a "good pointer" instead?